# Node.js: Request on proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, request

I need a request to go through a proxy;
dependencies: cheerio, request, request-promise.

````
request({
    url: "URL",
    path: '/xxxx.html',
    method: "GET",
    json: true,
    body: myJSONObject
}, function (error, response, body){
    console.log(response);
});```
````

Comment: Please be more descriptive

Comment: I need a request GET on proxy, and i need set body.
For example: https://programmerclick.com/images/69/0a93ecacf69bd1d5febb0a947f9a2ea5.png